# F# units of measure conversion based on type

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to write a "unit of measure" converter in F#.

I have defined two units of measure, `KWh` and `MWh` and I am trying to write a function to convert between the two that will pattern match on the numeric type.  I could have a float, decimal, int of KWh to convert to MWh.

```
[<Measure>]
type KWh

[<Measure>]
type MWh

// want to do this, but can't because x is not x:obj, 
// its something like x:float<KWh>
let toMWh x = 
    match x with
    | :? float<KWh>     -> x * (1.0<MWh>/1000.0<KWh>)
    | :? int<KWh>       -> // ...


// above code not valid f#
```

I'm not able to figure out how to correctly branch on type when I don't have a obj type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I'd just do the low-budget overloading solution:

```
[<Measure>] 
type KWh 

[<Measure>] 
type MWh 

type Convert = 
    static member toMWh (x:float<KWh>) =  x * 1.0<MWh> / 1000.0<KWh>
    static member toMWh (x:int<KWh>) =  x * 1<MWh> / 1000<KWh>

printfn "%d" (int(Convert.toMWh(5000<KWh>)))
printfn "%f" (float(Convert.toMWh(5500.0<KWh>)))
```

That said, someone may come up with a clever, type-safe way to do it with `inline` (I'm not sure offhand if it's possible).  I would avoid your run-time matching, since it sacrifices static type-safety (which is kinda the point of units).  (Also, it is impossible to do run-time matching of units anyway, since units are erased during compilation.)

Comment: This is working, but to improve the philosophy of UoM conversion, you should multiply by **something that has physical sense**, e.g. `1000.0<KWh/MWh>`. The rule of thumb is whether your conversion value presents in reference books. In plain English, `1000.0<KWh>` is useless, but `1000.0<KWh/MWh>` says, "there is 1000 KWh in 1 MWh".